# How to get data from SharePoint host header site collection to another host header site collection with in same Web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, host-header

While Getting data from SharePoint host header site collection to another host header site collection using rest API we are getting 401 unauthorized error. please help.

Source URL: http://cph.vconnect.com
Dispaly Site URL: http://mysite.vconnect.com

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getMarqueeListItem();
});

// occurs when a user clicks the read button
function getMarqueeListItem() {
    var listName = "CorpCommunication";
    var url = "http://cph.vconnect.com";
    getListItems(listName, url, function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
      alert(items.length);
    }, function (data) {
        marquee_list.empty();
        alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again");
    });
}

// READ operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// siteurl: The url of the site that the list is in. 
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function getListItems(listName, siteurl, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
        });

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should enable cors in web.config
https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/

Or use another options: ECMAScript or custom wcf-service and access data in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, In given article he describe about 2 web application but my issue is different team sites with in same web application

Comment: In this case you have the same issue: same-origin policy doesn't work [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)